# DeepAI API error - {"err": "error processing given inputs from request"}

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'm a noobie at Python and was just messing around, but now I'm really curious why it isn't working. I'm currently trying to build a telegram bot that generates an image based on the text given to the bot. I think there might be a problem with my DeepAI api? When I click this link: https://api.deepai.org/api/text2img i always get the error

> {"err": "error processing given inputs from request"}

. The bot is linked but gives me the error as in the code below. My code below:

```
import requests
import json
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

def text_to_image(update, context):
    # Get the text from the user
    text = update.message.text

    # Set up the DeepAI API request
    api_key = "{{ api }}"
    headers = {
        "api-key": api_key
    }
    data = {
        "text": text
    }

    # Make the request to the DeepAI API
    response = requests.post("https://api.deepai.org/api/text2img", headers=headers, json=data)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        update.message.reply_text("An error occurred while generating the image. Please try again later.")
        return

    # Get the generated image from the response
    response_json = response.json()
    image_url = response_json["output_url"]

    # Send the generated image to the user
    context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, photo=image_url)

def main():
    # Set up the Telegram bot
    updater = Updater(token="{{ api }}", use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Add the text_to_image handler
    text_to_image_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, text_to_image)
    dispatcher.add_handler(text_to_image_handler)

    # Start the bot
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've tried changing code and different things but nothing seems to work, i'm really stuck right now

Comment: So where in your code is the error generated? Or is it your deepai link that generates an error when you try to reference it?

Comment: The code actually works fine and I can run it, the TG bot gives me the response ‘ An error occurred while generating the image. Please try again later.’ which references to the status code. Looks lije something wrong on the DeepAI side? Idk for sure

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it's an error on the API side of things. The status code of the API server depends on traffic and account/key.

Things to do:
Check if your API key is valid and wait when server works on google, then try to run your code